Signup screen resized wrong
I have a screen where the user has to put some credentials and either choose to sign up or to login. " I added alignment top center but still doesn't help.
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Logo()),

              //   SignUpButton(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              LoginButton(),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}

class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  UserProfileState createState() => UserProfileState();
}

class UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {
  // Map<String, dynamic> _profile;
  bool _loading = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Subscriptions are created here
    //  authService.profile.listen((state) => setState(() => _profile = state));

    //authService.loading.listen((state) => setState(() => _loading = state));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      //  Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20), child: Text(_profile.toString())),
      Text(_loading.toString())
    ]);
  }
}

class LoginButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Form(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
        child: TextFormField(
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Nume si Prenume',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Antra', fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black)),
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
        child: TextFormField(
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Email',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Antra', fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black)),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 30,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 62,
        width: 300,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
              )),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(
            'Login',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
        Icon(
          Icons.email,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 40,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 62,
          width: 300,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
              ),
            ),
            child: Text(
              '        I already have account',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
              );

              // )
              //        // Navigate to second route when tapped.
            },
          ),
        )
      ])
    ])));
  }
}

Added alignment , trying scaffold with scroll view , still nothing works. Should I add instead of a scaffold something else? sized box doesnt work either. HERE A PHOTO OF THE OUTCOME

You've said that you want it aligned center, but where are you seeing it align with this code?

provide a pic of the actual and expected results

https://imgur.com/a/WseYTUk just to make an idea about what I am speaking
